# How to automatically search URL’s, and check if a string exists

Tags: python

For example: searching a website and it keeps checking all the pages  (assuming they have their own URL) of it for a string like “and”, and sees if it exists in any of them.)

So it has that URL, and one part of it is variable, (the page number).
Then there may be a loop that sets the page number from 1 to (maxPagenumber).

I want to make a program which checks these at a fast rate. (5 searches per second at least.)

Comment: No I have only tried opening a page, having it search and that is it. Very very inefficient. I have no idea of what to do.

Comment: Are you talking about something like a __web crawler/spider__? Search for those terms on your favourite search engine.

Answer (score 0):

Use [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/)

- Build the scraper
- Feed the list of urls to it
- Search the HTML for the string you're after

If you are hitting the same domain you will need to use a proxy middleware otherwise you will get blacklisted if you hit the site too hard

You can definitely achieve more than 5 per second, scrapy is able to make concurrent requests

** If the pages have javascript loaders, then use the [scrapy-splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash) plugin

Comment: I suppose this could work. Have python generate that list using a loop then copy and paste that into scrapy. Thanks! I will give this a shot.

Comment: At what rate would you imagine it could search at. In terms of searches/minute

Comment: @Simplex1 That depends entirely on the request limits set by the site administrator and the complexity of the website. One of the websites I'm scraping allows up to 1500 requests per minute for one section of the website and 100 rpm for another. Scrapy is built on top of Twisted, so you are unlikely to be limited by CPU/memory/GIL.